# Scss error, is it a bug or did i make a mistake?

Tags: sass

```
.myclass {

    position: absolute; 

    $positions: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7;
    @each $position in $positions {
        &.x#{$position} {
            top: #{$position}%; 
        }    
        &.y#{$position} {
            left: #{$position}%; 
        }   
    }

}
```

Did i make something wrong? VsCode tells me [scss] term expected aftr the % signs, can you tell me is it a bug or did i make a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

That should work just fine:

```
#{$position}#{"%"}
```

UPDATE:

I think compiler recognizes % as start of placeholder selector (so it expects placeholder name after percent sign), it's required in this case that you declare "%" as string.

*"Placeholder selectors" @ sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html*

Comment: I think compiler recognizes `%` as start of placeholder selector (so it expects placeholder name after percent sign), it's required in this case that you declare "%" as string. "Placeholder selectors" @ http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html